# Glassfish concurrency, tuning, performance

Tags: multithreading, performance, concurrency, glassfish, threadpool

I have a glassfish server with the following configuration in cluser

- tcp - Thread Pool Size ( 200 )
- Acceptor Threads ( 5 )
- Xmx ( 3048m )
- Xms ( 1024m )
- Protocols->http-listener-1->HTTP ( Max Connections = 256 )

> Nginx is used as the load balancer and I have pretty good
>   configuration for this. When I tried to fire 200-300 concurrent users
>   in 10 secs with JMeter, performance started decreasing after 200th
>   request. Please see the attached screenshot. You can see the sampling
>   time, it's really bad. **What changes needs to be done in order to
>   improve the performance. How can I hit 1000 to 2000 concurrent users
>   in 5 to 10 secs without affecting performance.**
>
> I am using MySql as the backend database.
>
> I do have memcached caching stuff installed in server. Actually none
>   of the requests wait for mysql queries to complete. I am caching and
>   it fetches everything from memcache so I don't think there needs to be
>   an improvement in database side.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
## http redirects to https ##
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xxxx;

    # Strict Transport Security
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxxx;

    location / {     
        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;  
    }   

    ## default location ##
    location @backend {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass    http://glassfish_servers;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

    # force timeouts if the backend dies
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    #proxy_redirect off;

    # set headers
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxxx.key;

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
    ssl_protocols                   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                     ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;                   

}
```

Comment: There are too many variables here to really get into it. There's not really one question here, this needs a bit of investigation. First you need to gather more data. How busy is your thread pool? How full is your heap? Is it resizing a lot? How busy is your DB connection pool? You need to get good data of each component in the system being tested so that you can make a change, retest, and see the how each component is affected. Currently, we're not sure of where the bottleneck really is, so that's a good place to start.

Comment: Also, as an aside, it's generally a good idea to set min/max heaps to the same size and to use AJP connectors over HTTP for better performance between Nginx and GlassFish

Comment: I have managed to reduce the sample time, latency and connect time by changing the configuration parameters in nginx. Please see the new attached screenshots. I attached 2 screenshots. One by sending direct request to https and the other to http. Http requests are redirected internally to https in nginx. Mike, you can find that the delay is twice higher than sending to https . Do you know how to eliminate the redirect delay ? anything I have to do in nginx ? Attached nginx configuration too. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Which is the best tool for load testing. I am using jmeter. But I have a problem with that. I put google.com, even for google, it shows warning when it reaches around 3000 request / min. I think jmeter is buggy. Mike, any idea ?